# Changing lines in a file

Tags: linux, text, file, replace

I'd like to replace (as an example) the text of lines 5-15 in a file with the text from lines 6-15 from another file.  But I'd like to do this over about 2000 files, and would rather not have to do it manually.

I could script something in perl, but I'd like to try to do it with any built-ins possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use sed

```
for file in bar baz bam; do
    newfile=$(mktemp)
    (sed '5q' $file; sed -n '6,15p' foo; sed '1,15d' $file) > $newfile
    mv -f $newfile $file
done
```

or Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.6;  # lexical filehandles need Perl >= 5.6

# usage: $0 foo bar baz bam
# replaces lines 4-15 of qw(bar baz bam) with lines 6-15 of foo 

my @ins;

{
    open my $fh, shift;
    while (<$fh>) {
        push @ins, $_ if 6 .. 15;
        last if $. >= 15;
    }
}

$^I = '';

while (<>) {
    print if not 5 .. 15;
    print @ins if $. == 4;
}
continue {
    close ARGV if eof ARGV;
}
```

but `ed` works too.

```
echo '6,15wq foo-part' | ed foo
for i in bar baz bam; do
    echo -e '5,15d\n4r foo-part\nwq' | ed $i
done
rm -f foo-part
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for files in PATTERN ; do
  sed -n '1,14p' $files > newfile.$files
  sed -n '6,15p' ANOTHERFILE >> newfile.$files
  sed -n '15,$p' $files >> newfile.$files
done
```

Note: it's not resource effecient, but I'm writing it on a really powerful server ;-)
And there are several other ways to do it.

Comment: Sed is the way to go here! It was designed for this task.

Comment: Since the files are iterated one after one, I feel it would be clearer and better to write "for file in ..." instead of "for files in ...".

Comment: You're right from a grammar point of view. And from subjective point of view: I can name my variables like cVGHJJKAHFDJHSJFO9878932KHJKHJK too. If I can understand it later.